# GCC type of variable in a macro

Tags: c, gcc, macros

I want to embed the name of a variable type in a string or variable name.

For example:

```
#define SYM(var) sym_##typeof(var)##_num
int foo;
typedef struct s_type { int x; } s_t;
s_t bar;
int SYM(foo) = 1;
int SYM(bar) = 2;
```

would generate

```
int foo;
int sym_int_num = 1;
int sym_s_t_num = 2;
```

Any idea how I can do this, without passing the type name to the macro?

Comment: C doesn't have type introspection. Not possible afaik.

Comment: @ArjunSreedharan the question is also tagged gcc, which supports typeof: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Typeof.html

Comment: @mah: however the pre-processor doesn't have access to the result of `typeof`, so I don't think it will be too useful here.

Comment: @MichaelBurr I agree with that. Even if it was available at the preprocessor level, it would certainly cause problems in the requested context for types like "int *", "struct mystruct", even "unsigned int".

Comment: The problem with this is that `SYM(foo)` will get expanded to `sym_typeof(foo)_num`, which is somewhat less than useful...

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done in C, even if GCC has the typeof() operator.  It took me a bit of thinking to see why.

Typeof is interpreted during semantic processing.  The preprocessor runs long before any semantic processing is performed, and even before any syntactic processing.  The preprocessor only works with text tokens, not with the language semantics, and typeof() is definitely a semantic property.

(C++ templates can do type substitution because the are interpreted during semantic processing.)